# SQL Server 2008 created/last updated trigger issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, triggers

I am using this trigger in order to fill in the `CreatedDate` and `LastUpdated` columns (of type `datetime`) in a table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trCreatedDate ON [LasMTest]
FOR INSERT 
AS
    UPDATE [LasMTest] 
    SET [LasMTest].Created = getdate(),
        [LasMTest].LastModified = getdate()
    FROM [LasMTest] 
    INNER JOIN Inserted ON [LasMTest].[ID] = Inserted.[ID]
GO
```

When I check the table, the dates are off by just a fraction of a second.

```
Created LastModified    ID
2013-03-19 09:24:32.920 2013-03-19 09:24:32.930 4
2013-03-19 09:26:39.890 2013-03-19 09:26:39.900 5
```

How can I modify the trigger so that they are both the exact time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the interaction of your *two* triggers that's causing the problem.

If, instead, you set both columns to *default* to `getdate()` and ditch your `insert` trigger, it should work - the `INSERT` won't also cause an `UPDATE`.

The alternative is to author your `INSERT` trigger as an `INSTEAD OF` trigger that performs an `INSERT` rather than an `UPDATE` (and thus, also, avoids the `UPDATE` trigger firing).

---

If you do want to write it as an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, it would be something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trCreatedDate ON [LasMTest]
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
    INSERT INTO LasMTest (/* Column List */,Created,LastModified)
    SELECT /* Column List */,getdate(),getdate() from inserted
GO
```

`INSERT`s into the triggering table in an `INSTEAD OF` trigger don't (thankfully) cause the trigger to be fired recursively. If `ID` is an `IDENTITY` column, then it should appear in the column lists above (it hasn't been generated yet).

Comment: what is the syntax for the INSTEAD OF?

Comment: The default constraint for Created and delete the insert trigger worked just fine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trCreatedDate ON [LasMTest]

FOR INSERT 

AS
Declare @CurrentDate Datetime
Set @CurrentDate=getdate()
UPDATE [LasMTest] SET [LasMTest].Created=@CurrentDate,[LasMTest].LastModified=@CurrentDate

FROM [LasMTest] INNER JOIN Inserted ON [LasMTest].[ID]= Inserted.[ID]

GO
```

Comment: I have tried that too, doesn't quite work, probably because I have another trigger for UPDATE which I think is the cause of the discrepancy. `CREATE TRIGGER trLastModifiedDate ON [LasMTest]

FOR UPDATE 

AS

UPDATE [LasMTest] SET [LasMTest].LastModified=getdate()

FROM [LasMTest] INNER JOIN Inserted ON [LasMTest].[ID]= Inserted.[ID]` basically it seems that actually triggers when I do INSERT which I want it to trigger only when a row is UPDATED, not created, how to change that?

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to avoid the UPDATE trigger when doing the update from INSERT. This is called [Nested Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190739.aspx). One easy solution is to use [`CONTEXT_INFO()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187768.aspx) to communicate to the nested UPDATE trigger code that you are already in an INSERT trigger so it suppresses itself:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trCreatedDate ON [LasMTest]
FOR INSERT 
AS
    SET CONTEXT_INFO 0xDEADBEEF;
    UPDATE [LasMTest] 
    SET [LasMTest].Created = getdate(),
        [LasMTest].LastModified = getdate()
    FROM [LasMTest] 
    INNER JOIN Inserted ON [LasMTest].[ID] = Inserted.[ID];
    SET CONTEXT_INFO NULL;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER trModifiedDate ON [LasMTest]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @context varbinary(128);
    SET @context = CONTEXT_INFO();
    IF @context is NULL
    BEGIN
       UPDATE [LasMTest] 
          SET [LasMTest].LastModified = getdate()
        FROM [LasMTest] 
        INNER JOIN Inserted ON [LasMTest].[ID] = Inserted.[ID];
    END
GO
```

However such an approach is fragile. An exception can leave the context_info set and suppress all subsequent UPDATE triggers in the session. This requires adding TRY/CATCH blocks. And you always run the risk of an application using `CONTEXT_INFO` for *its own* purposes and ruining your scheme.

Another solution is to make the UPDATE trigger smart. It can check the [`UPDATE(Created)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx) inside the UPDATE trigger and suppress any action if the `Created` column was modified. This works by convention, because you know that the only place that updates the `Created` column is the INSERT trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trModifiedDate ON [LasMTest]
FOR UPDATE
AS
    IF NOT UPDATE(Created)
    BEGIN
       UPDATE [LasMTest] 
          SET [LasMTest].LastModified = getdate()
        FROM [LasMTest] 
        INNER JOIN Inserted ON [LasMTest].[ID] = Inserted.[ID];
    END
GO
```